# R: error when trying add an axis to an histogram plot

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
PIBTOTALnominal<-c(13556.76, 15255.59, 16658.13, 18558.56, 20112.05, 21722.82, 21045.36,    23300.21, 25648.44, 27737.39, 28277.22)

length(PIBTOTALnominal)
mean(PIBTOTALnominal)
sd(PIBTOTALnominal)
limclase=seq(min(PIBTOTALnominal),max(PIBTOTALnominal),length=9)
hdatos=hist(PIBTOTALnominal,breaks=limclase,plot=FALSE)

hdatos

interv=hdatos$mids[2]-hdatos$mids[1]

ejex=c(hdatos$breaks[1]-interv, hdatos$breaks, max(hdatos$breaks)+interv)

ejelimx=c(hdatos$breaks[1]-interv,max(hdatos$breaks)+interv)

ejelimy=c(0,max(hdatos$counts)+3)

histo<-hist(PIBTOTALnominal,main="Masa de filtros",ylab="Frecuencia", xlab="m (mg)",
labels=TRUE,breaks=limclase, xlim=ejelimx, xaxt="n", ylim=ejelimy, col="gray") 

axis(side=1, at=ejex)
```

but when I use `knitr` to produce a pdf file, I get the following error:

```
Error in axis(side = 1, at = ejex) : plot.new has not been called yet
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> axis
Execution halted
```

What is the mistake I made?

Comment: Try putting all the code into a single chunk. Not sure if that will make a difference but I wasn't able to reproduce your problem. [I can knit to pdf without the error](https://imgur.com/yv4Z77u). Might want to update `rmarkdown`.